# jquery prepend <span> without automatically adding the closing tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a `<span>` tag around the contents of the `<a>` tag.

The HTML renders without js like this:
`<a href="#">Link Here</a>`

I would like to add the `<span>` inside the link like this: `<a href="#"><span>Link Here</span></a>`

My idea was to 'prepend' the opening span and 'append' the closing tag to the a, however I can't get past the prepend.  When I try to prepend the 'span' it automatically adds the closing `</span>` tag.  Here is the script I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.button2').prepend('<span>');
});
```

Here is what it is rendering:

```
<a href="#"><span></span>Link Here</a>
```

Is there a way to prepend ONLY the opening tag so that I can append the closing later, or another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner) to wrap the *contents* of the `a.button2` element in a `span`:

```
$('a.button2').wrapInner('<span />');
```

Comment: How can you achieve this with wrapping the element?

For Example:

I have html output as follows ...

`<table>

   <tbody>

      <tr id="foo">

         <td>Some content here ...</td>

      </tr>

      <tr id="bar">

          <td>Something here ...</td>
   </tr>

 </table>

   </tbody>

</table>

`
  
And before #bar ... i need '<table>' tag, but when using the .wrapInner or .prepend functions i get '<table></table>' automatically.

Any ideas? Thanks.